# necessary conditions to comment

Tags: support, comments

How many points one must have to be able to comment. I find myself compelled to comment in "answers" as I can not directly comment an answer which is not practical and cause me lose points.

Answer (score 3):

Everything related to reputation levels can be found [on the privaleges page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges).

Specifically to [comment on posts other than your own](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) you need at least 50 rep points on beta sites (such as this is at the moment).